# Joomla or Croogo?

Tags: cakephp, frameworks, content-management-system, joomla

I am deciding which CMS to use for a new application. It is either Joomla or Croogo but I need some advise on available resources online (tutorials, extensions etc) vs familiarity with framework.

I have used Joomla but never developed anything for it. Whereas I have developed with CakePHP framework and the only CMS I find reliable is Croogo.

I need to complete my new project (from design to code) in a fairly short amount of time (about 3-4weeks) so I was thinking of going for Joomla due to the resources available. But
, I will need to learn how to develop with it in case I need some customizations or modify existing extensions if need to.

My worries are whether the errors/issues that may come along will slow me down as I am not familiar with how the code works. And with Joomla 1.6 release, old extensions are being converted.

I don't mind learning Joomla if it's easy and wouldn't take long.

Using Croogo on the other hand seems like a safer decision but I will need to develop quite a few things from scratch.

Here are my comparisons:

Joomla

- Lots of resources online
- Should save time
- Never developed with it before
- Some say the MVC  pattern is not good?

CakePHP

- Familiar with the framework
- Not as many resources online

Which would be a better choice?

EDIT: Let me add that the application I am developing needs to allow registered users to key in details, upload images, files for publishing to front-end users. There is also a payment gateway option and automatic PDF invoicing. There are a few other things as well but these are the key ones.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing a Joomla (full-blown CMS with zillions of pluings and themese) with the still-beta Croogo!!

Croogo might have potential is the future (based on the very nice MVC CakePHP), but it don't stand the competition with Joomla.

I used joomla for a while, most of the time you will not need to do anything manually. just grab couple of trusted extensions, get a ready-made template and customize it..

You are ready to launch it less than 10 hours..

Of course Joomla 1.5 lacks a lot of important stuff (e.x. ACL), but you can live without it, or use any ACL component.

Comment: If I were to develop plugins for 1.5, will it be a tideous process to convert it for 1.6? It seems to me that 1.6 is not yet proven stable. Say I were to choose Joomla, should I go for 1.5 or 1.6 right away?

Comment: It is not hard to move 1.5 plugins to 1.6. And version 1.6 is already stable, just go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has matured over time as a php cms with loads of community support and extensions available croogo has still to achieve maturity.